# Object inside an object in React Native

Tags: react-native, object

I'm getting an odd error with object inside an object in React Native. I set some state variables in my constructor:

```
this.state = {
   payAmount: 0,
   selectedPaymentMethod: 0,
   btnDisabled: true,
   cardDetails: {
     cardName: '',
     cardNumber: '',
     cardCVV: '',
     cardExpiration: '',
     cardPostalCode: ''
   }
};
```

Then, when I try to access "cardDetails", it returns `Can't find variable: cardName`

Code:

```
const data = { cardName, cardNumber, cardCVV, cardExpiration, cardPostalCode } = this.state.cardDetails;
```

Can't I use object inside an object in react native?

Thank you!

Comment: can u past the whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const { cardName, cardNumber, cardCVV, cardExpiration, cardPostalCode } = this.state.cardDetails;
```

and yes, You can create object inside object.